# how to change the sequence of the legend

Tags: matlab, plot, legend, matlab-figure, figure

I want to change the sequence of the legend.

See the figure.  I want the sequence to be: green and `data2`, blue and `data3`, black and `data4`, red and `data1`.

Could anyone give a demo?

[image]

Comment: I think, the following link provides best answer to your query, without needing to replot.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/39104135/842808

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the order in which the plots are added to the figure, and then call `legend` normally. That should do it.

---

You can also do it as follows. First get handles to the individual plots:

```
h1 = plot(1:5);
hold on
h2 = plot(11:15, 'r');
```

Then call `legend` specifying the order:

```
legend([h1 h2],'plot1','plot2')
```

or

```
legend([h2 h1],'plot2','plot1')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that this solution requires explicitly returning and keeping track of the graphics objects (h1, h2) as they are plotted. For a similar solution that does not require that, see my answer in a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66681832/6292794

Answer (score 1):

In case, you have already made the plots or if you added some plot at the end, which want to reorder to somewhere in middle, you can try this way:

1) Go to `show Plot Tools and Dock Figure`.

2) `Delete` the data (which you want to move to bottom). Then `undo` delete.

3) Refresh `legend`.

Comment: This seems to have stopped working somewhere around R2017a. Now if I restore the lines they end up in the original order and nothing changes. Is there a workaround?